# How to check Android App Permission in Windows

Tags: python, android, automation, android-permissions, privacy

When one app is installed on Android, it will ask access for several kind pf permissions. I have thousands of apps install package and I try to find out what permissions each app requests. I want to finish this job on Windows. Do we have any tool or how to use some programming language like Python to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but what are you trying to say/do?

Comment: I have edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

Apk file is simple zip archive.
You can extract data from the archive and read AndroidManifest.xml entries.
Check lines like the `<uses-permission android:name="..."/>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll check the details